# How to draw 2 graphs at the same time in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have charts like this:

[image: chart example]

I need to draw these graphs in python so that later I can evenly distribute the points inside this curve. I tried to implement like this, but it's far from what I need:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X = range(0,3)

y = [x*x for x in X]
z = [2-x for x in X]

plt.plot(X, y, color='r', label='x^2')
plt.plot(X, z, color='g', label='2-x')

plt.xlabel("X")
plt.ylabel("Y")

plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

Comment: Use a different `X` for each curve: `x1 = np.linspace(0, 1); y = x1 ** 2; plt.plot(x1, y)` and `x2 = np.linspace(1, 2); z = 2 - x2; plt.plot(x2, z)`

Answer (score 0):

Two remarks:

1. The lines you get are "overlaying" since you share the same `x`. However, in your desired output, the `x` of the square function extends from `0` to `1` and the x of the linear function extends from `1` to `2`.
2. You get only three connected points, because `range()` only returns discrete integer values. `numpy.linspace()` returns evenly spaced numbers over a specified interval.

As @tdy mentioned in the comment, you should create two different x's for each curve:

```
x1 = np.linspace(0, 1)
x2 = np.linspace(1, 2)
```

Then you calculate the function values:

```
y1 = x1 ** 2
y2 = 2 - x2
```

Then you plot both:

```
plt.plot(x1, y1)
plt.plot(x2, y2)
```